# Beamer, PaloAlto

Tags: beamer

Good evening! 
I'm not expert of Beamer and I've a problem with PaloAlto:

1. I would like to have a logo on the top right corner if possibile;
2. I would like to have ''bar title'' without color instead blue;
3. In sidebar, the color of the text, white.

Here the code:

```
\documentclass[13pt]{beamer}
\usepackage [italian] {babel}
\usepackage [utf8] {inputenc}
\usepackage [T1] {fontenc}
\usetheme[width=1.5cm]{PaloAlto}          %controls the width of the sidebar
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{bg=red, fg=white}     %controls the color of the headline
\setbeamercolor{sidebar}{bg=red, fg=white}        %controls the color of the sidebar
\setbeamercolor{logo}{bg=red!70!black}

\makeatletter

\beamer@headheight=2\baselineskip     %controls the height of the headline, default is 2.5  

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\title[]{TITLE}
\author[]{NAME}
\date{DATE}
\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{Fig/Cattura.JPG}}
\section{Quadro generale}
\section{Assunzioni}
\section{Test}
\section{Incoerenze}
\section{Critiche}
\section{Proposte}
\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Thanks a lot for answers:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1. I would like to have a logo on the top right corner if possibile;>

```
\logo{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image}}
```

> 2. I would like to have ''bar title'' without color instead blue;

```
\setbeamercolor{title}{bg=white,fg=black}
```

> 3. In sidebar, the color of the text, white.

```
\setbeamercolor{section in sidebar shaded}{fg=white}
```